# Create React App executing tests with jest Unexpected token import

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jestjs, create-react-app

I am just a new developer on React. I have just starting a new app using the create-react-app plugin. After that I have customised my own App Component, but this is using some third party components which makes the `npm run test` (react-scripts test --env=jsdom) fails with an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

This error only happens for an import inside a dependency at node_modules I am using. For example, it gives no error on

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Since I am using the create-react-app plugin I do not know what I need to change to make it pass. However, it seems to be something related with some babel configurations missing.

I think I should not need to install babel-jest dependency since that is embedded with create-react-app.

I have also tried to execute, without success:

```
npm run test -- --no-cache
```

The package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "dhis2-hello-world",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "d2": "^28.3.0",
    "d2-manifest": "^1.0.0",
    "d2-ui": "^28.0.8",
    "d2-utilizr": "^0.2.15",
    "loglevel": "^1.6.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
   "rxjs": "^5.5.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "d2-manifest package.json ./public/manifest.webapp",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "manifest.webapp": {
    "name": "DHIS2 App Template",
    "description": "DHIS2 App Template",
    "icons": {
      "48": "icon.png"
    },
    "developer": {
      "url": "",
      "name": "DHIS2"
    },
    "activities": {
      "dhis": {
        "href": ".."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error:

`/node_modules/d2-ui/lib/app-header/HeaderBar.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`

PropTypes is being imported on a component at d2-ui which is being import at App component like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import HeaderBarComponent from 'd2-ui/lib/app-header/HeaderBar';
```

I was looking for a way to solve it without need to eject the project.

Could anyone give me some clues of how to solve that problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#running-tests) test documentation?

Comment: If you use create-react-app you should be ready to work on it without any modification. How did you create your app? Did you run `create-react-app my-app`? Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Yes, I have run ```create-react-app my-app```and I have looked into test documentation from them.

Comment: what is the dependency it is failing on

Comment: well, not enough informations here. Please provide your package.json and full error report.

Comment: If the dependency exports only ES6 modules, Jest will probably fail, as the jest preprocessor in create-react-app ignores `node_modules`. Either mock out the dependency in your test, raise an issue with the dependency to export commonjs too, or eject and change the `transformIgnorePatterns`.

Comment: Thanks guys! I have updated the question with more details.